# Acessing objects from differents files

Tags: python

Let's say i have two files like this:

TestClass.py

```
class Test:
    variable = None

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.variable = value
```

__main__.py

```
from TestClass import Test
TestObject = Test(123)
```

Doing the following works, but I don't like it much. Want to find a way to do this without passing the object as an argument.

access.py

```
def testFunction(TestObject):
    print TestObject.variable
```

Any ideas?

Anyways, thanks everybody for reading :)

EDIT: Thanks for the answers so far. The names were just an example, and importing the same module in many different files would mean different objects in memory doing the same function. I wish to access the object from **main**.py in any other module without having different copies of it in the memory.

Comment: Is your source file really called `__main__.py`? That seems unconventional.

Comment: Why do you want to access this object rather than copy it? Can't you simply store a copy of the object in `access.py` and then refer to that?

Comment: Who calls the function in access.py?  Why don't you just import TestObject from __main__ in access.py?  Import does not "copy" anything, it just makes the name available in another namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the commenters pointed out the solution here is to import.

As mike said, importing does not copy anything.

*test.py*

```
import test2
print test2.dog
```

*test2.py*

```
dog = "puppy"
```

*test3.py*

```py
import test2

print test2.dog
test2.dog = "not a dog anymore"
import test1
```

if you run

```
python test3.py
```

you will get the following

```
puppy
not a dog anymore
```

What is happening is test2 defines the variable. Importing it brings the variable under the test3 namespace. Then test3 changes the variable and imports test.py.

Similarly test.py imports test2 and prints the variable. Since it simply got the reference to the variable and **not** a copy the new value was printed and not the value originally put in.

If you ran

```
python test.py
```

you would get

```
puppy
```